# Google Spreadsheet clear content

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets

For the first time I am trying to make a spreadsheet function to clear a range with a function, but now im not quite sure how it works.

My function looks like:

```
function clearsheet() {
    var mineralsgas = SpreadsheetApp.getActive().getSheetByName('Minerals/Gas');
    mineralsgas.getRange('E6:E13').clearContent();
}
```

But i get a Parse Error.
Now I'm thinking I should make the function somewhere not in a cell and create a button to set it to?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your code is fine... from what I understand in your question I guess that your problem is "how to call that function from within the spreadsheet ?

You **can't** of course use that function like a custom function in a cell.

You have 2 possibilities : menu and buttons.

Menu are explained in the [documentation along with code examples](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/spreadsheet/spreadsheet#addMenu%28String,Object%29) reproduced below

```
// The onOpen function is executed automatically every time a Spreadsheet is loaded
 function onOpen() {
   var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
   var menuEntries = [];
   // When the user clicks on "addMenuExample" then "Menu Entry 1", the function function1 is
   // executed.
   menuEntries.push({name: "Menu Entry 1", functionName: "function1"});
   menuEntries.push(null); // line separator
   menuEntries.push({name: "Menu Entry 2", functionName: "function2"});

   ss.addMenu("addMenuExample", menuEntries);
 }
```

or you can draw a button (or insert an image ) and assign your function to it. Do it simply frim the spreadsheet interface (not possible to assign a function to a drawing programmatically) like illustrated below :

[image]![image]

Note that this feature is not yet available in new version of spreadsheet.